# How can we defeat a team of 6 tracers?

Tags: overwatch

The enemy decided to go full tracer, and now they are taking the lead.

What heroes can we use to defeat them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tracer's key strength is her mobility and hard-to-predict movement patterns. However, she is very fragile and if she is caught out, she will die. Also, while she does well at fighting 1v1, she does very poorly against a grouped team (unless she manages to stick her ult).

Tank-wise, Reinhardt is a good option as his barrier doesn't allow her to build up ultimate charge and forces her to attack you from the sides. By narrowing her avenues of approach, your allies can cover your flanks. Winston is also a good choice. Although his shield is stationary (unless you place it on the payload), his weapon fires in a cone which allows him to track her much easier.

Heroes with CC are also helpful against Tracer. McCree's flashbang can stun a flanking Tracer, allowing him to pick her off with ease. Mei's Endothermic Blaster does the same, although it requires locking on to Tracer for 2 seconds. Junkrat's Steel Trap can root Tracer, but it's an immobile trap. While Roadhog can hook a Tracer for an easy kill, his large HP pool and hitbox make him an easy target for ultimate charge.

Situationally, S:76 can be useful although risky given the aiming needed to connect with his heavy pulse rifle. However, his ultimate counters Tracer very handily given that he'll automatically target her no matter how she dodges unless she makes it out of line-of-sight. Pharah is also a situational pick. Tracer's Pulse Pistols have heavy damage falloff and Pharah is usually high up enough in the air where Tracer can do little damage to her. While Pharah is also not as likely to hit Tracer with her rockets if she's paying attention, most Tracers won't be looking up as she attempts to flank your teammates.

Torbjorn is also deadly to a Tracer because his turret auto-locks onto her and her damage falloff prevents her from taking it out at range.

Comment: Great answer. As a side question, would sentries be agood approach?

Comment: As in... Bastion? Or Symmetra? Bastion's problem is that while he can chew up a Tracer, he is very vulnerable to flanking without a team to support him. Also, short of popping his ultimate at just the right time, Tracer's ult can one-shot and he is very easily stuck due to his stationary sentry mode. Symmetra's sentries do slow Tracer down and her lock-on primary fire is very handy against Tracer, but be aware that Symmetra is rather fragile and most likely can't take on Tracer 1v1.

Comment: I think the vertical aspect is a key part to taking on a group of Tracers.  They're vertically challenged to begin with, and that allows Widowmakers and Pharahs get to places a Tracer can't.  The flip side of this is that Tracers are more likely to disengage with enemies they can't reach rather than try to fight it out from a distance.  I still believe a well supported Bastion (for instance with Reinhardt and Mercy) can counter a team of Tracers, as long as they aren't allowed to get close with an ult.

Comment: This is how you beat a team of tracers :) https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ngkle/go_five_tracers_they_said_itll_be_fun_they_said/

Answer (score 0):

As someone who is extremely effective with tracer, what I absolutely hate to see when I play is a junkrat. He's by far the best counter for her. Ive been one shoted by his grenade launcher so many times. The steel trap may be hard to make hit but once it does, it deals an immediate 70 damage and stays clinched longer than 3 seconds making her rewind completely useless. You'll probably still die a good bit due to low hp but you'll be killing tracers left and right. Mcree isnt as good at countering as everyone says. At least not if the tracer is halfway decent. His flashbang doesn't last long enough and the reach is awul so it's easy to dodge.

Answer (score -3):

Short answer: McCree upclose then flashbang and rightclick, a good widowmaker ir hanzo can one shot tracer, Soldier76 can out damage tracer, a Pharah and possibly genji.